# sklearn svc: count number of elements in classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am a newbie to sklearn and ML in general, I am using svm classifier on a training data, training data is split into 2 classes , let's say 0 and 1, training data set has 20000 elements. The test data has 1000 elements, I am able to fine tune svc for upto 99% accuracy. I would like to know, out of the 1000 training elements, how many belong to class 0 or 1? Is there any function that I can use? I hope I explained it correctly. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sklearn.metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics) module. For example [classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html#sklearn.metrics.classification_report) might be interesting for you, as the report also contains *support* column, which represents number of samples predicted for each of the individual classes.